# Application with a lot of activities

Tags: android

I would like to create app with a lot of activities but I don't know if its good idea. Application should have hundreds activities because its app to 3 month learning system. Every day have few tasks to do so in my app will be more than 500 activities. Is that a good idea or should I do it in any other way?

Comment: Use fragments. It'll make life easier.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I will be in home because i'm working now :)

Comment: does every activity have its own different UI? if they share common UI but use different data simply use one activity and load the data from any kind of data repository

Comment: No, every activity have this same UI. The only one change is task to do in lessons.

Comment: so use one activity

Comment: Thank you :) I will read more about your idea in home :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating 500 Activities is the most bad idea. 
It takes a lot of resources.

If you use same layout in 500 activities, Use `RecyclerView`. [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: How is recyclerview equivalent to an activity?

Comment: If you use same layout in 500 activities, Show day learning list with `RecyclerView`. And User click a list item, Show detail information with one fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0):

As a main idea, we should not repeat a code. Your acivities  UI is same and you need different data to present. You can use recyclerview and each item has its own specific data and task to present.